# F# - Weird FileNotFound Exception

Tags: f#, streamreader

I basically just have this:

```
open System.Net
open System.IO 

let reader = new StreamReader("students.txt")
let csv = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

For some reason this throws a File Not Found Exception. It tells me it could not find the file at "C:\Users\Shane\ownCloud\Home\Assign18\Assign18\bin\Debug\students.txt" even though that is exactly where the file is. This happens even if I put the full file path to students.txt, or if I move it to another location.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I'm just not very used to using Windows (only running it for Visual Studio). So when I named the file "Students.txt", I didn't realize that Windows already had a file extension for that file that it was hiding from me. So the whole time, the file was actually called "Students.txt.txt"

Comment: To avoid this in the future: Control panel -> Folder Options -> "View" tab -> untick "Hide extensions for known file types" :)

Comment: FYI for "strongly typed" access to file paths, there is a [FileSystem type provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Management/FileSystemProvider.html) (part of the FSharp.Management NuGet).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to run the program as an administrator - [`new StreamReader(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx) does not mention a specific exception when file permissions are violated, and thus may be wrapping it.

Note that [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx) and the aformentioned [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) methods mention specific exceptions when encountering access violations, and thus may throw more descriptive (helpful) exceptions.